Aiken onchain check original message wrapped in CIP30 signData signed message
I've a message that will be signed by user's wallets, the thing is wallets follow CIP30 for signing a message (payload in Sig_structure below), meaning the final signed message is like this:
Sig_structure = [
       context : "Signature" / "Signature1" / "CounterSignature",
       body_protected : empty_or_serialized_map,
       ? sign_protected : empty_or_serialized_map,
       external_aad : bstr,
       payload : bstr
   ]

So the original message gets wrapped inside Sig_structure. On chain I'm using verify_signature to validate the user signed that message, the thing is I want to make sure the message I'm verifying is actually wrapping the original message otherwise I'm just validating the wallet sign a message but I don't know if it's actually a wrapped of the original one.
Signed message (Sig_structure) is a CBOR, so I'd like to know what options Aiken provides (if there is any) to make that kind of verification. I was thinking on instead of parsing (I haven't found a way to parse CBOR data) that CBOR signed message, going the other way around and create a CBOR using cbor.serialise and then compare both strings. The problem is I can't find a way to put a plain text in the CBOR. Here is my attempt so far:
  let data =
    [
      "Signature1", // the context
      #"a201276761646472657373581d603dce7844f36b23b8c3f90afba40aa188e7f1d3f6e8acd1d544ed1da9", // the body_protected, it's a map for algorithm and address { 1: -8, "address": "..." }
      #"", // external_aad is empty
      #"4d494e547c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e666f6f", // original message
    ]
  trace bytearray.to_hex(serialise(data))

which generate this CBOR:
9f4a5369676e617475726531582aa201276761646472657373581d603dce7844f36b23b8c3f90afba40aa188e7f1d3f6e8acd1d544ed1da94058254d494e547c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e666f6fff

Structure:
9F                                      # array(*)
   4A                                   # bytes(10)
      5369676E617475726531              # "Signature1"
   58 2A                                # bytes(42)
      A201276761646472657373581D603DCE7844F36B23B8C3F90AFBA40AA188E7F1D3F6E8ACD1D544ED1DA9 # "\xA2\u0001'gaddressX\u001D`=\xCExD\xF3k#\xB8\xC3\xF9\n\xFB\xA4\n\xA1\x88\xE7\xF1\xD3\xF6\xE8\xAC\xD1\xD5D\xED\u001D\xA9"
   40                                   # bytes(0)
                                        # ""
   58 25                                # bytes(37)
      4D494E547C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002E666F6F # "MINT|\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000.foo"
   FF                                   # primitive(*)

[
  h'5369676E617475726531',
  h'A201276761646472657373581D603DCE7844F36B23B8C3F90AFBA40AA188E7F1D3F6E8ACD1D544ED1DA9',
  h'',
  h'4D494E547C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002E666F6F'
]

Which is slightly different from the one coming from CIP30:
846a5369676e617475726531582aa201276761646472657373581d603dce7844f36b23b8c3f90afba40aa188e7f1d3f6e8acd1d544ed1da94058254d494e547c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e666f6f

Structure:
84                                      # array(4)
   6A                                   # text(10)
      5369676E617475726531              # "Signature1"
   58 2A                                # bytes(42)
      A201276761646472657373581D603DCE7844F36B23B8C3F90AFBA40AA188E7F1D3F6E8ACD1D544ED1DA9 # "\xA2\u0001'gaddressX\u001D`=\xCExD\xF3k#\xB8\xC3\xF9\n\xFB\xA4\n\xA1\x88\xE7\xF1\xD3\xF6\xE8\xAC\xD1\xD5D\xED\u001D\xA9"
   40                                   # bytes(0)
                                        # ""
   58 25                                # bytes(37)
      4D494E547C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002E666F6F # "MINT|\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000.foo"

[
  "Signature1", 
  h'A201276761646472657373581D603DCE7844F36B23B8C3F90AFBA40AA188E7F1D3F6E8ACD1D544ED1DA9', 
  h'',
  h'4D494E547C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002E666F6F'
]

You can see "Signature1" is hex encoded when using cbor.serialise and also is adding an extra FF at the end
   FF                                   # primitive(*)

Even though I ended up having the same CBOR that isn't a good approach since wallets can decide to add/remove some optional fields in Sig_structure breaking this logic.
